# Get name of closest business using Swift's CoreLocation

Tags: swift, gps, mapkit, cllocation, reverse-geocoding

I want to get the name of a business given its latitude and longitude.  There are other APIs that do this like Google Places, but I'd rather not have additional dependencies in my app if I can help it.  Is there any way to do this via CoreLocation in Swift? I know you can get an address "name" from a latitude and longitude using this:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
    placemarks?.first?.name
}
```

But this only gives me the street number, not the actual name of the business like "Costco" or whatever it's really called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Areas of Interest** information from **CLPlacemark**, as in documentation:

> Examples of an area of interest are the name of a military base, large
>   national park, or an attraction such as the Eiffel Tower, Disneyland,
>   or Golden Gate Park

Check it here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clplacemark/1423673-areasofinterest

And here for all info available:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clplacemark